# Insert elements into an array from a given range on a BST

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

So I have to insert the elements from a BST that fall in a given range into a list. The problem I'm facing is that it only inserts the element if `root->elem` is in the range. If it isn't obviously it isn't inserted.
Here is the code:

```
template<typename E, typename F>
ListArray<E> BinarySearchTree<E,F>::findRange(E min, E max) {

ListArray<E> elems;
if (isEmpty()) {
    return elems;
}
if(inRange(root->elem,min,max)){
    elems.insertLast(root->elem);
    root->left.findRange(min,max);
    root->right.findRange(min,max);
} else {
    if(root->elem < min){
        root->right.findRange(min,max);
    } else if (root->elem > max){
        root->left.findRange(min,max);
    }
}

return elems;
}
```

For the sake of simplicity let's say that we are operating with `int` since I'm forced to use templates.
I guess it has to have something to do with the fact that i'm not returning the list from any recursive case but I don't know haw to propperly do it.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Using a concatenation function (that was also given to me) I was able to return the list from the recurssion and concatenate it with the "first one" without the need of lambda expressions or private functions.

The code is the following:

```
template<typename E, typename F>
ListArray<E> BinarySearchTree<E,F>::findRange(E min, E max) {
    ListArray<E> elems;
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return elems;
    }
    if(inRange(root->elem,min,max)){
        elems.concat(root->left.findRange(min,max));
        elems.insertLast(root->elem);
        elems.concat(root->right.findRange(min,max));
    } else {
        if(root->elem < min){
            elems.concat(root->right.findRange(min,max));
        } else if (root->elem > max){
            elems.concat(root->left.findRange(min,max));
        }
    }
    return elems;
}
```

Note that if the element is in the range I first call the `concat(...)` function before inserting the element. This way it gives the elements in ascending order.

The `concat()` function looks like this:

```
template<typename E, int N>
void ListArray<E,N>::concat(const ListArray<E,N>& l) {
    if (this->length() + l.length() > N) {
        throw MyException("The list is empty");
    }
    for (int i=0;i<=l.lastIndex;i++) {
        insertLast(l.storage[i]);
    }
}
```

To finish this off the implementation of the BST looks like this:

```
template<typename E, typename F>
class BinarySearchTree {
public:
    //All the different methods   
    ListArray<E> findRange(E min, E max);    
private:
    struct Node {
        E elem;
        BinarySearchTree<E,F> left;
        BinarySearchTree<E,F> right;
    };

    Node *root;
    F compare;
    //Some private functions
    bool inRange(E num, E min, E max);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a private implementation function that will let you pass the array by reference to each recursive call.

```
template<typename E, typename F>
class BinarySearchTree {
    /*Whatever else is implemented*/
private:
    void findRange_impl(ListArray<E> & elems, E min, E max) {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        if(inRange(root->elem,min,max)){
            elems.insertLast(root->elem);
            root->left.findRange_impl(elems, min, max);
            root->right.findRange_impl(elems, min, max);
        } else {
            if(root->elem < min){
                root->right.findRange_impl(elems, min, max);
            } else if (root->elem > max){
                root->left.findRange_impl(elems, min, max);
            }
        }
    }
    
public:
    ListArray<E> findRange(E min, E max) {
        ListArray<E> elems;
        findRange_impl(elems, min, max);
        return elems;
    }
};
```

I don't know how your search tree is implemented, so I don't know whether the `root` variable updates correctly at each level of the tree, but I'm presuming that that's a contingency that your code already accounts for.

### EDIT:

Given the inability to make edits to the class header (which tells me your instructor is just super-committed to teaching bad design principles), we'll need to instead define a local class within your function to give us an inner function that we can recurse upon.

```
template<typename E, typename F>
ListArray<E> BinarySearchTree<E,F>::findRange(E min, E max) {
    ListArray<E> elems;
    
    struct Inner {
        ListArray<E> & elems;
        E min, max;
        Inner(ListArray<E> & elems, E min, E max) : elems(elems), min(min), max(max) {}
        void findRange_impl(BinarySearchTree<E,F> * node) {
            if (node->isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
            if(inRange(node->elem,min,max)){
                elems.insertLast(node->elem);
                findRange_impl(node->left);
                findRange_impl(node->right);
            } else {
                if(node->elem < min){
                    findRange_impl(node->right);
                } else if (node->elem > max){
                    findRange_impl(node->left);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    Inner inner(elems, min, max);
    inner.findRange_impl(root);
    return elems;
}
```

As far as I'm aware, there shouldn't be any [language/technical] restrictions to writing code like this.

Comment: I can't do that. I can only implement this function as public. The code was handed to me except for this very function so I expect it to work. I can give a pastebin link with the full implementation if needed.

Comment: @nipsn Are you allowed to use lambda expressions? Because there's an easy fix to adapt the code I wrote if you are.

Comment: Nope. Didn't even heard of them until now.

Comment: @nipsn Okay, I've updated my post with a version that uses a local class inside the function implementation. A lambda would be very similar, but without the boilerplate class definition surrounding the implementing function.